# Can not find _socket module

Tags: python, sockets, module

In the Python library file Python34/Lib/socket.py the _socket module is imported:

```
import _socket
from _socket import *
```

but I couldn't find _socket anywhere in the library.

Could anybody explain what is _socket?

Comment: Why are you importing `_socket` instead of `socket`?

Comment: I'm not importing anything yet, it's  Python library imports  _socket.

Answer (score 3):

`_socket` is a shared library that provides the C implementation of much of `socket.py`. (Indeed, the first line of `socket.py` says the module is a wrapper around `_socket`.) It isn't meant to be used directly.

Comment: Thank you  for your reply. Does it mean, that everything that I ever will be need to know about socket class, is visible in  python code? Why there is no _socket.h include file?